# Can you localize a Custom.plist file?

Tags: ios, swift

I know that you can localize the Info.plist file by creating InfoPlist.strings etc... But is it possible to localize text that comes from a custom plist.

Part of my application has some static strings inside a .plist file and I want to localize the strings inside the .plist file.

[image]

Is there something similar to InfoPlist.strings that you can do with custom property lists?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What stops you from localizing those strings in Localizable.strings? Which code responsible for reading that .plist file?

Comment: Either you put the "Key" of the Localized.strings file as the value, or you can localize the plist, using its custom plist.strings that is localized

Comment: @Asperi Let me try that - didn't consider it as an option

Comment: @Larme going to give it a shot and report back

Comment: Solved by localized the .plist file itself and following the instructions in this medium post: https://medium.com/@dcordero/a-different-way-to-deal-with-localized-strings-in-swift-3ea0da4cd143

Answer (score 1):

Simply press "Localize" on the .plist file you've created and follow this post if you want to use genstrings: https://medium.com/@dcordero/a-different-way-to-deal-with-localized-strings-in-swift-3ea0da4cd143